# use existing elasticsearch7/8 for vector search vs adding dedicated vector database

Tags: elasticsearch, embedding, vector-database

I already have elastic search engine installed and I want to add openai ada embedding for lexical similarity score support for better multilingual and synonyms in my application.

Should I add a new vector database or just use existing elasticsearch ?

My current es version is latest opensearch 7.11, willing to migrate to es8 if necessary

(There might be 10 kilos of indexes, at most 1m docs per index, store.size per index is typically 100kb-100mb.)